# Lagrange Multipliers for Function Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

For some constant $A > 1$ I am trying to solve the constrained minimization problem
minimize $F(u)$ in $C$
subject to $H(u) = 0$.

Here $F(u) = \int -u dx$ and $H(u) = \int \sqrt{1 + (u')^2} dx - A$, where our integral is from 0 to 1.

I have two main questions:

1. What is the geometric interpretation of this problem?
2. If I assume that $u$ is a smooth minimizer I am to use the Lagrange Multiplier
   Theorem to compute the Euler–Lagrange equations. Derive a diﬀerential equation for $u$∗.

I have heard that this is called the isoparametric problem.  Is it fair to say that the geometric interpretation here is that of minimizing area given a certain perimeter?  Is using the Lagrange Multiplier Theorem similar to using Euler-Lagrange to minimize an unconstrained functional?  Thank you!

Comment: You can check this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331081/simple-resource-for-lagrangian-constrained-optimization/331623#331623

Comment: Right, but that is for minimizing a function not a functional as in this case.

Comment: Did you study weak variations?

Comment: What the hell is "unconstrained functional"? There's literally nothing on Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279518/constrained-variational-problems-intuition/281284#281284) to a different question. The same procedure should work for your problem:

1. Set up the Lagrangian with multiplier $\lambda$:
   $$L(u, \lambda) = F(u) + \lambda \, H(u)$$
2. Solve the following system for $u$ and $\lambda$:
   \begin{align*}
   \partial_u L(u, \lambda) &= 0 \\
   \partial_\lambda L(u, \lambda) = H(u) &= 0\end{align*}
   Typically, this can be done by using the Euler-Lagrange-equations for the first equation. This gives you $u$ in dependence of $\lambda$. Then, choose $\lambda$, such that the corresponding $u$ solves the second equation.

Comment: What if $F$ and $H$ depend on the derivative of $u$ ? Then the Euler-Lagrange equation would involve derivatives of $\lambda$ with respect to $x$, so how can one solve for it ?

Comment: If $H$ is a scalar constraint, then also $\lambda$ is only a scalar. The situation is completely different, if $H$ is a functional constraint.

Comment: Please check this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4615558/euler-lagrange-with-derivative-of-multipliers for precisely that situation. Any comment is greatly appreciated.