# Euler-Lagrange with derivative of multipliers

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be some simply connected domain and consider the functional

\begin{align}
V\left[u(x,y),v(x,y),w(x,y)\right]=\int_\Omega dxdy\:\left(u_x v_y-u_y v_x\right)w,
\end{align}

We wish to find the functions that maximize $V$ constrained to

\begin{align}
(u_x)^2+(v_x)^2+(w_x)^2&=1\\
(u_y)^2+(v_y)^2+(w_y)^2&=1.
\end{align}

If we introduce the multipliers $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ for the constraints, we have the Lagrangian

\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}=\left(u_x v_y-u_y v_x\right)w-\frac{\lambda_1}{2}\Big[(u_x)^2+(v_x)^2+(w_x)^2-1 \Big]-\frac{\lambda_2}{2}\Big[(u_y)^2+(v_y)^2+(w_y)^2-1 \Big]
\end{align}

that leads to the equations

\begin{align}
0&=u_x v_y-u_y v_x+\left(\lambda_1 w_x \right)_x+\left(\lambda_2 w_y \right)_y\\
0&=-\left(wv_y-\lambda_1 u_x\right)_x+\left(wv_x+\lambda_2 u_y\right)_y\\
0&=\left(wu_y+\lambda_1 v_x\right)_x-\left(w u_x-\lambda_2 v_y\right)_y
\end{align}

The question is, how to solve for the multipliers $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ ?

In the typical classroom examples the constraints do not depend on the derivatives of the dependent variables, thus the derivatives of the multipliers don't appear in the equations and one can solve for them algebraically. Here, however, that's not the case.

(We impose just the boundary condition $w\left(\partial \Omega\right)=0$, leaving $u$ and $v$ free. This should not be relevant for the question, which is only about how to consistently eliminate the multipliers.)

Comment: To begin with, note that $(\lambda_{1,2})_x = (\lambda_{1,2})_y = 0$, since they are constant quantities.

Comment: @Abezhiko The multipliers are constants only when the constraint is an integral constraint. Since here the constraint holds at every point they (the multipliers) depend on the coordinates as well. That is $\lambda_{1,2}=\lambda_{1,2}(x,y)$.

Comment: I think there is no easy way to solve for the multipliers. You just get a coupled nonlinear system of five PDEs.

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/744758/2451

Comment: @gerw True. That's not really a problem. My concern is which boundary conditions to impose on the multipliers.

Comment: What are the boundary conditions on $u,v,w$?

Comment: @Qmechanic As I mentioned, $w$ vanishes on the boundary. $u$ and $v$ are free, meaning that among all the possible conditions we seek for the ones that maximizes $V$.

Answer (score 3):

5 coupled non-linear PDEs seem a too difficult task to solve. In this answer, we will only discuss the boundary conditions for the Lagrange multipliers $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

1. The [De Donder/Weyl polymomenta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Donder%E2%80%93Weyl_theory) are
   $$ {\bf p}_u~=~\begin{pmatrix} v_y w -\lambda_1 u_x \cr 
   -v_x w -\lambda_2 u_y \end{pmatrix}, $$
   $$ {\bf p}_v~=~\begin{pmatrix} -u_y w -\lambda_1 v_x \cr 
   u_x w -\lambda_2 v_y \end{pmatrix}, $$
   $$ {\bf p}_w~=~\begin{pmatrix} -\lambda_1 w_x \cr 
    -\lambda_2 w_y \end{pmatrix}, $$
   $$ {\bf p}_{\lambda_1}~=~\begin{pmatrix} 0 \cr 
    0 \end{pmatrix}, $$
   $$ {\bf p}_{\lambda_2}~=~\begin{pmatrix} 0 \cr 
    0 \end{pmatrix}. $$
2. OP lists the following boundary conditions:
   $$ u,v \text{ free and }  \left.w \right|_{\partial \Omega}~=~0. $$
   We assume that this also means that the derivatives of $u,v$ are free.
3. The infinitesimal variation of OP's ${\cal L}$ reads
   $$\delta {\cal L} ~=~\sum_{\phi=1}^5\left\{ \underbrace{\left(\frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial\phi} -\nabla\cdot{\bf p}_{\phi} \right)}_{\text{EL expression}} 
   \delta \phi+ \nabla\cdot\left({\bf p}_{\phi}\delta \phi \right)\right\},$$
   where $\phi$ runs over the 5 variables $u,v,w,\lambda_1,\lambda_2$.
4. In order for the variational principle for OP's ${\cal L}$ to be well-posed, we must demand that $$  {\bf p}_u \text{ and } {\bf p}_v \text{ are parallel to the boundary  at the boundary } \partial \Omega,$$
   cf. the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem).
5. Generically this implies that
   $$ \left.\lambda_1\right|_{\partial \Omega}~=~0 \quad\text{ and } \quad \left.\lambda_2\right|_{\partial \Omega}~=~0, $$
   which in turn are also sufficient conditions for well-posedness.

Comment: @Qmechanics Thank you. Why is it that we need the polymomenta to be parallel to the boundary ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the argument is that we have that $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{p}=0$, then it follows that $\int_{\partial \Omega} d \mathbf{N} \cdot \mathbf{p}=0$. Can this integral vanish without $\mathbf{N} \cdot \mathbf{p}=0$ ?

Comment: The variation $\delta\phi $ vanishes on the boundary, so the divergence term vanishes without demanding $\mathbf{p}_\phi=0$, isn't it ? I don't want to impose $\lambda_1|_\partial=\lambda_2|_\partial=0$ because that would only lead to a trivial solution (that is a minimizer, but not a maximizer of $V$.)

Comment: There is something that doesn't quite agree with your answer. Take the first of the equations listed and integrate it over $\Omega$, thus we have $\int_\Omega dxdy\:\{u,v\}_{x,y}=-\oint_{\partial \Omega}d\mathbf{N}\cdot(\lambda_1 w_x,\lambda_2 w_y)$, but the left hand side is the projected area of the surface $(u,v,w)$, which has to be non-zero for the solution to be a maximum (if its zero the solution is trivially a minimum). So I simply cannot impose $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0$ on the boundaries.